# Move files from various subfolders into sub-subfolders

Tags: shell, files, directory

I have various folders each containing files as such:

```
/.example1/example1.txt
/.example1/example2.txt
/.example2/example1.txt
/.example2/example2.txt
etc.
```

And want to find a way to move each of the files into a subfolder of its parent folder, eg:

```
/.example1/folder/example1.txt
/.example1/folder/example2.txt
/.example2/folder/example1.txt
/.example2/folder/example2.txt
etc.
```

Any ideas on a quick and simple way to do this for large amounts of files? I've already tried playing around with `find` but without much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using GNU versions of `find` and `mv` like this:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -execdir mv -vt ./folder/. {} +
```

Where we constrain `find` to look for regular files 2 levels deep and then using the `-execdir` option to move the selected file(s) into the subdirectory `folder` which is co-adjacent to the selected file(s).

Answer (score 0):

```
find /.example1 -name example*.txt" -type f | awk -F\/ '{ for(i=1;i<=NF-1;i++) {  path=path$i"/" } } END { print "mv "$0" "path"folder/"$NF }' | sh
```

Do a find on all the example files in the directory and then parse the returned output using awk, forming a move command that is executed with sh

Comment: This would require a separate command for each `.example1`, `.example2` etc. folder though?

Comment: OK, I've amended the answer to use awk instead.

Comment: It still only uses the `/.example1` folder to start in (also missing a " from the `-name` argument). After replacing it with a . instead, it just ends with an interactive shell prompt instead, so I don't think the arguments are being passed correctly from awk.